# How to fix jerky, frame-skipping CSS3 :hover transition of transform property in Chrome? Works in all other browsers

Tags: css, animation, transform, transition

Here's the [JSFiddle of the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/2zMVw/)

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="shot">

</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.body {
  background-color: #ecf1ff; }

.shot {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #ff8346;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; }


.shot:hover {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(45deg);
  -moz-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(45deg);
  -o-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(45deg);
  -ms-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(45deg);
  transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(45deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; }
```

This works fine in Firefox, Safari and IE... In Chrome it seems like it first 'squashes' the rectangle down and then applies the perspective in the last frame. It's not transitioning the perspective properly. Is this a known issue or is it something that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the perspective also to the base (unhovered) element.

[corrected fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/2zMVw/1/)

Added CSS:

```
.shot {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px);
}
```

The problem is that the perspective in the base element is undefined; different browsers can handle this in different ways.